# VueJS 2 - Cannot use variables from imported file in App.vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

There must be a really simple solution I have tried everything.

**App.vue** file

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 @import 'src/assets/styles/_variables.scss'
 img {
    height: $height;
 }

</style>
```

**_variables.scss** file

```
height: 27px;
```

Even if I move `img { height: $height; }` I still get an error. For the life of me I just want access to `$height` from an imported scss file. This must be so simple?

error seen in this screen shot:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JevNA.jpg)
**Raw Error:**

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-06ade8f3","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: 
  img {
  ^
      Invalid CSS after "img": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
      in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vuejs-portfolio/src/App.vue (line 63, column 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, it will solve your problem.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 @import 'src/assets/styles/_variables.scss';
 img {
    height: $height;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Ive added a screen shot to the original question

Comment: Please put a semicolon (;) at the end of @import 'src/assets/styles/_variables

Comment: gah a simple semicolon